# How to politely say "I don't know anybody"

Tags: synonyms

I have to fill out a form about scholarship application and there is a case in which I have to indicate name of  contact in that country and  my question is how to say I don't know anybody there politely. 
Thank you for considering my request.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write “None known”, but I fear they may  perhaps use that answer to screen out candidates. I would definitely first try to seek advice with your home country’s consulate within the country that you are applying for scholarship in.